# Suspend linux from KDE Plasma 5 lockscreen

Tags: arch-linux, kde, screen-lock, plasma5

TLDR: How to suspend from KDE LockScreen?

I'm using KDE's default lockscreen which you can somewhat configure [image: Kde lockscreen config]
But I haven't found a way to suspend my PC from the lockscreen, so I had to enter my password and then suspend every time I needed it which is very inconvenient.

Currently I modified KDE plasma lockscreen files (LockScreenUi.qml in particular) to add Suspend button. But maybe the is a simpler way to do this?

Also yes, I have seen [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/69vase/suspend_button_disabled_on_lock_screen/dh9uei8/) and a few posts on kde forums without any solutions.

My configuration:

```
uname -a
Linux neko 4.15.14-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 28 17:34:29 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

kded5 --version
kded5 5.45.0

plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.12.5
```

The patch itself, it basically adds Suspend button with default icon and uses PowerDevil KDE service to suspend (found this usage logout files)

USE AT YOUR OWN RISK:

```
--- /usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/lockscreen/LockScreenUi.qml 2018-05-01 16:03:40.000000000 +0300
+++ backups/kde-plasma-lockscreen/LockScreenUi.qml  2018-05-05 19:56:59.764353585 +0300
@@ -31,6 +31,18 @@

     colorGroup: PlasmaCore.Theme.ComplementaryColorGroup

+    function performOperation(what) {
+        var service = dataEngine.serviceForSource("PowerDevil");
+        var operation = service.operationDescription(what);
+        service.startOperationCall(operation);
+    }
+
+    PlasmaCore.DataSource {
+      id: dataEngine
+      engine: "powermanagement"
+      connectedSources: ["PowerDevil"]
+    }
+
     Connections {
         target: authenticator
         onFailed: {
@@ -174,6 +186,11 @@
                         onClicked: mainStack.push(switchSessionPage)
                         // the current session isn't listed in the model, hence a check for greater than zero, not one
                         visible: (sessionsModel.count > 0 || sessionsModel.canStartNewSession) && sessionsModel.canSwitchUser
+                    },
+                    ActionButton {
+                      text: i18nd("plasma_lookandfeel_org.kde.lookandfeel", "Suspend")
+                      iconSource: "system-suspend"
+                      onClicked: performOperation("suspendToRam")
                     }
                 ]
```

**EDIT1:**

There is already a report for the feature on [KDE bugtracker](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392798) (thanks [Lekensteyn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/8250/lekensteyn) for the link)

Comment: Did you try to look for / file a bug report for this feature request?

Comment: @AF7 Well, I have seen multiple posts about it but no bug/feature requests on kde trackers. Maybe I should file one, indeed. But I wanted to try finding a solution here before I go there, maybe I just missed it somewhere.

Comment: There are two feature requests related to this, see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392798 (and a linked report from 2014).

Comment: Your patch does not seem to do anything on `kded5 5.48.0` and `plasmashell 5.13.4` (Manjaro). Am I missing the place where I should look?

Comment: @Pastafarianist well, I have it on `kded5 5.49.0` and `plasmashell 5.13.4` (Arch) and it works (I have Suspend button in lockscreen), perhaps the original file updated and the patch doesn't apply cleanly, but you can always add it manually.

Comment: Your patch worked great, but after a couple of months the changes in `LockScreenUi.qml` were lost. Supposedly due to an update. So it would be great to find a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 5):

thanks for the patch, it works like a charm!

same to handle the physical power key:

```
      Keys.onPressed: {
+            if (event.key == 16777399) performOperation("suspendToRam")
```

confirmed to work on `kded5 5.67.0` and `plasmashell 5.17.5` (Gentoo).

UPDATE 2020-06: refreshed patch for kde-plasma/plasma-workspace-5.18.5

```
--- /usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/lockscreen/LockScreenUi.qml.orig    2020-06-25 00:50:49.181771074 +0300
+++ /usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/lockscreen/LockScreenUi.qml 2020-06-25 00:56:23.750323655 +0300
@@ -38,6 +38,18 @@
 
     colorGroup: PlasmaCore.Theme.ComplementaryColorGroup
 
+    function performOperation(what) {
+        var service = dataEngine.serviceForSource("PowerDevil");
+        var operation = service.operationDescription(what);
+        service.startOperationCall(operation);
+    }
+
+    PlasmaCore.DataSource {
+      id: dataEngine
+      engine: "powermanagement"
+      connectedSources: ["PowerDevil"]
+    }
+
     Connections {
         target: authenticator
         onFailed: {
@@ -125,6 +137,8 @@
             }
         }
         Keys.onPressed: {
+            if (event.key == 16908292) performOperation("suspendToRam")
+            if (event.key == 16777399) performOperation("suspendToRam")
             uiVisible = true;
             event.accepted = false;
         }
@@ -279,6 +293,11 @@
                         anchors{
                             verticalCenter: parent.top
                         }
+                    },
+                    ActionButton {
+                        text: i18nd("plasma_lookandfeel_org.kde.lookandfeel", "Suspend")
+                        iconSource: "system-suspend"
+                        onClicked: performOperation("suspendToRam")
                     }
                 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!
Works well.

My laptop has a sleep key as well, so I added one more line:

```
      Keys.onPressed: {
+            if (event.key == 16908292) performOperation("suspendToRam")
            uiVisible = true;
            event.accepted = false;
```